# how to carry out induction in abstract algebra？

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

I fail to understand how the induction step is carried out in this proof.Can anyone  help?Thanks!

Comment: In fact a bit confusing because induction is not needed. Denote n as the degree of $B$. If deg(A)<n, we immediately have the desired representation, otherwise in a simple way , a polynomial is constructed with degree less than n, for which we again trivially have the desired representation. It is rather a proof by cases than an induction proof. Of course this also fits in the scheme of an induction proof, but it unnecessarily creates potential for confusion.

Comment: @Peter: If you actually write down the proof you are painting in the air with your arms, you'll see it's an induction.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I have noticed that, but I explained the point occuring in this case.

Comment: @Peter The inductive step does *not* construct a polynomial of degree $< \deg B\,$  with trivial rep. Rather, by (complete) induction it constructs a rep for a polynomial $A'$ of *lower* degree than $A,\,$ viz. $\,A' = A- a_m X^{m-n} B.\,$ Rearranging this rep of $A'$ yields a rep for $A\ \ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $n = deg B$. They are proving the statement by inducion on $m = deg A$. The base case is $m < n$. If $m \geq n$, then they find another polynomial $A'$, in this case $A' = A - B a_m X^{m - n}$, which has degree smaller than $m$, so we can deal with it by induction hypothesis. The quotient-and-remainder representation of $A'$ is used to find that of $A$.

I suppose there are two things that you may find bothering, and why you didn't recognize the induction. First, that the base case is not just one case but a bunch of them. Notice that here this was fundamental: the induction step in the proof only works for $m \geq n$. Also, notice that in this case proving it for $m = 1$ is not less work that proving it for $m < n$: it was a one-line proof for all of these cases.

The second thing you may find bothering is that we are not only using the induction hypothesis for $m - 1$, but for any polynomial with degree strictly smaller than $m$. This is called *complete* or *strong* induction: where in the induction step, you use the hypothesis that the statement is true up to $m - 1$, and not just for $m - 1$. On the wikipedia page for induction it's explained well.